# Private Key Problem

Tags: blockchain.info

I made an blockchain.info wallet and I want to obtain the private keys for my addresses.

In my old blockchain.info wallet, I could find the private keys, but in the new one the private keys are not there.

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think blockchain.info stores private keys unless they are imported. Rather they use BIP 32 to derive private keys from a seed and just store the seed. The seed can be exported as a BIP 39 mnemonic - it is the recovery phrase that you wrote down when you created the wallet and can be found in the settings.

This recovery phrase can be used with any software that supports BIP 39, so just enter it into any such software which also shows you the private keys and you can get your private keys from there.

You can use https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ to do this. However you should never enter your seed into a website; rather you can just download the source code for this site and open that up locally in your browser (preferably with your Internet connection also disabled at this time).

Comment: As far as I remember, Blockchain.info's recovery phrase is local to their own site - You cannot use it to directly restore your keys via BIP39 in another wallet.

Comment: They changed that. The recovery phrase used to be something for their site. It is now a BIP 39 mnemonic.

Answer (score 0):

Blockchain.info recently made an update to their wallet.

Before the update, they were generating a random wif therefore an address, but after the update, they are generating mnemonic phrase (BIP 39 - 32) and derive wallets from that mnemonic phrase.